# Get phone call duration based on phone number

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

Is it possible to access call duration information by phone number from call log using react native?

For example search for number **031582856** and check if this number exists in call log, if it does, get phone call duration and send this information to my web app using prepared http request.

I was trying to find a way / app for my web app to verify the phone call was completed searching for different solutions - call trackers, dialers with call api, call centers, but no luck for what i am trying to achieve.

I am not expecting full solution here just some guidelines or ideas what would be the easiest way to achieve this. You can also suggest ideas using kotlin/java i just need to know what would be the best approach for me since i am not experienced mobile developer.

Comment: have you code anything ?

Comment: @Lucifer no, not just yet, i need some kind of guideline what would be the best approach for this, i will dig into code myself, dont need you to code for me, just theoretical help with ideas :)

Comment: In that you instead of asking question, you need to discuss this in chat room first.